# Is It possible to read WebResource.axd in C# code behind 

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, webresource.axd

the simple question is, Is It possible to read WebResource.axd in C#, please don't ask why I am trying that. I want to read WebResource.axd file run-time when Index.aspx page requested.